# В каких из предложений союз повторяющийся?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены

> И вот красные облака появились над заливом(,) и стали стремительно приближаться.
>
> И он снова простился со мной(,) и пообещал вернуться через пару недель.
>
> И Акатош извлёк из сердца своего пригоршню горящей крови(,) и влил в руки Алессии.
>
> И как же мне с этим заработать состояние(,) и сделать себе имя?

Нужны ли запятые в отмеченных местах? У Розенталя есть следующее правило:

> Между однородными членами предложения, соединенными повторяющимся союзом *и*, ставится запятая, если первое *и* является присоединительным (стоит после точки): *И вспоминали прошлое, и старались объяснить себе, как всё это произошло*.

Там же:

> *И нагнулся старый атаман, и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную спутницу на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома* (Г.).

Я не уверен, к каким из приведенных мной предложений применимо это правило.

Comment: Союзы соединяют однородные элементы. Повторяющиеся стоят непосредственно перед ними.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**У [Гоголя](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1070/p.14/index.html)** (Н. В. Гоголь. Миргород. Тарас Бульба, XII) нет запятой между однородными **сказуемыми,** так что вероятно здесь ошибка. **[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=101#pp101)** имел в виду другие пары однородных членов:

Парные группы однородных членов, в свою очередь, могут соединяться повторяющимся союзом: И нагнулся старый атаман и стал отыскивать свою люльку с табаком, неотлучную спутницу **на морях и на суше, и в походах и дома** (Г.); Среди рек есть и большие и малые, и спокойные и буйные, и быстрые и медленные; Снаряды рвались и близко и далеко, и справа и слева.

Во всех приведенных примерах запятая между однородными сказуемыми **не ставится**. Первый союз ***И*** — **присоединительный.** Нет перечислительной интонации. Второй союз — одиночный **соединительный,** запятой нет.

**Примечание.**  Можно предположить, что предложение у Гоголя допускает перечисление: *И нагнУлся **старый атаман,** и стал отЫскивать свою люльку с табаком...*   Но здесь подлежащее стоит на втором месте, то есть особая структура. Поэтому каждый из союзов И относится непосредственно к сказуемым —  соответственно, их можно рассматривать как повторяющийся союз И...И.

Сравнить: *И простИлся он со мной, и пообещал вернУться через пару недель.*